# Serialize page content, into xml file

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have a very weird bug, going on....

I have my xml here:

**This is correct!**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Title>Title Text</Title>
  <Subtitles>
    <Subtitle index="0">
      <Text>Sub title</Text>
    </Subtitle>
    <Subtitle index="1">
      <Text>Sub title</Text>
    </Subtitle>
  </Subtitles>
  <Content>
    <Images>
      <ImageSource src="http://www.placehold.it/760x236" border-width="8px" border-color="#F4F2F3" />
    </Images>
    <Text>
      <![CDATA[here i need a place for a huge text's and stufff]]>
    </Text>
  </Content>
</Page>
```

Up until here every thing is ok, after i serialize it like so...

```
try
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TOut));

    XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Indent = true
    };

    // get xml source file
    var source = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", SettingResolver<Settings>.BaseFolder, Resolver.Settings.Pages.PageCollection[pageName].Source);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(source, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(fs, settings);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, o);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ExceptionHandler(new ErrorArgs("Serializing faulted!", e));
}
```

Here is the element that i have a problem with it...

```
public class Content
{
    [XmlElement("Images")]
    public Images Image { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public String ContentText
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private static readonly XmlDocument DummyDoc = new XmlDocument();

    [XmlElement("Text")]
    public XmlCDataSection ContentTextCData
    {
        get { return DummyDoc.CreateCDataSection(ContentText); }
        set { ContentText = (value != null) ? value.Data : null; }
    }
}
```

I get a result of this XML:
**This one is not ok and the one after**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Title>Title Text</Title>
  <Subtitles>
    <Subtitle index="0">
        <Text>Sub title</Text>
    </Subtitle>
    <Subtitle index="1">
        <Text>Sub title</Text>
    </Subtitle>
  </Subtitles>
  <Content>
    <Images>
      <ImageSource src="http://www.placehold.it/760x236" border-width="8px" border-color="#F4F2F3" />
    </Images>
    <Text>  
    <![CDATA[here i need a place for a huge text's and stufff]]>         
    </Text>
  </Content>
</Page>------------------>
</Page>
here i need a place for a huge text's and stufff
here i need a place for a huge text's and stufff
here i need a place for a huge text's and stufff
 </Content>
</Page>
```

Or this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Title>title</Title>
  <Subtitles>
    <Subtitle index="0">
      <Text>test</Text>
    </Subtitle>
    <Subtitle index="1">
      <Text>test</Text>
    </Subtitle>
  </Subtitles>
  <Content>
    <Images>
      <ImageSource src="http://www.placehold.it/760x236" border-width="8px" border-color="#F4F2F3" />
    </Images>
    <Text><![CDATA[just a text + +++++++++++++++++++++++++Hropj
+++++++++++++++++++++++++Hropj
]]></Text>
  </Content>
</Page></Text>
  </Content>
</Page>
```

The question is why this kind of bug happens?
*** I have noticed one weird thing, if i save the file it's ok, but if i delete the the text it appends to my text, every thing i deleted.

Comment: What is being asked here? What's the problem with the actual output and what's the desired output?

Comment: As you can see the first example is correct one! But thank i will edit the questiom

Comment: Why are you using a CData section for this? To avoid escaping issues?

Comment: Yes and i have to preserve the positions of text, for example if it's line break or newline or what ever

Comment: @John Willemse i have noticed one weird thing, if i save the file it's ok, but if i delete the the text it appends to my text, every thing i deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange... this could more than likely be the result of a bracket mismatch caused by certain characters in the ContentText during serialization. What happens if you set the XmlWriterSettings encoding property to unicode?

Comment: Nope still doesn't work, maybe show me a code example, please

Comment: Also, try HTML encoding the ContentText so that any special characters aren't causing problems during serialization. 'set { System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(ContentText = (value != null) ? value.Data : null); }'